# Appending Strings in Java/C# without using StringBuffer.Append or StringBuilder.Append

Tags: c#, java

at a recent interview I attended, the programming question that was asked was this. Write a function that will take as input two strings. The output should be the result of concatenation.

Conditions: Should not use StringBuffer.Append or StringBuilder.Append or string objects for concatenation;that is, they want me to implement the pseudo code implementation of How StringBuilder or StringBuffer's Append function works.

This is what I did:

```
    static char[] AppendStrings(string input, string append)
    {
        char[] inputCharArray = input.ToCharArray();
        char[] appendCharArray = append.ToCharArray();
        char[] outputCharArray = new char[inputCharArray.Length + appendCharArray.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < inputCharArray.Length; i++)
        {
            outputCharArray[i] = inputCharArray[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < appendCharArray.Length; i++)
        {
            outputCharArray[input.Length + i] = appendCharArray[i];
        }
        return outputCharArray;
    }
```

While this is a working solution, is there a better way of doing things?

Comment: Why are you calling `ToCharArray()`?

Comment: @SLaks: Blame it on the interview tension on a new country. :-)

Answer (score 5):

is LINQ legal? strings <del>are just</del> can be treated as an enumeration of chars, so they can be used with LINQ (even though there is some cost involved, see comments):

```
string a = "foo";
string b = "bar";

string c = new string(a.AsEnumerable().Concat(b).ToArray());
```

or with your method signature:

```
 static char[] AppendStrings(string input, string append)
 {
   return input.AsEnumerable().Concat(append).ToArray();
 }
```

Comment: Not enough privileges to vote it up. But that was smart! Real awesome smart.

Comment: You don't need to call `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: @Slaks: I tried w/o which doesn't compile - only alternative is using static method `string.Concat()` which seemed out of scope given the question - but maybe not `string c = string.Concat(a,b)` would be the simplest solution otherwise.

Comment: I don't think it is fair to say "just" here... they *can act* as an enumeration of chars, but that isn't the same. Also, this may result in a briefly oversized list - it isn't free.

Comment: I take that back; I hadn't realized that limitation.

Answer (score 5):

You can call `CopyTo`:

```
char[] output = new char[a.Length + b.Length];
a.CopyTo(0, output, 0, a.Length);
b.CopyTo(0, output, a.Length, b.Length);

return new String(output);
```

If they don't like that, call `.ToCharArray().CopyTo(...)`.

You can also cheat:

```
return String.Join("", new [] { a, b });
```

---

```
return String.Format("{0}{1}", a, b);
```

---

```
var writer = new StringWriter();
writer.Write(a);
writer.Write(b);
return writer.ToString();
```

Comment: +1. Aaargh! Damn it! I completely forgot of ICollection.CopyTo

Comment: Except that, as it turns out, `String` doesn't actually implement `ICollection`.

Answer (score 2):

I would've done something like the following (argument checking omitted for brevity)

```
public static string Append(string left, string right) {
  var array = new char[left.Length + right.Length];
  for (var i = 0; i < left.Length; i++) {
    array[i] = left[i];
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < right.Length; i++) {
    array[i + left.Length] = right[i];
  }
  return new string(array);
}
```

Comment: It is more of what I did (although, I did redundantly convert them to array). No?

Comment: @Magic, it's close but your method allocates 3 arrays vs. mine which allocates 1 array.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can just use `concat` which does not use StringBuilder or StringBuffer.

```
String a = "foo";
String b = "bar";
String ab = a.concat(b);
```

The source for String.concat(String) from Oracle's JDK.

```
public String concat(String str) {
int otherLen = str.length();
if (otherLen == 0) {
    return this;
}
char buf[] = new char[count + otherLen];
getChars(0, count, buf, 0);
str.getChars(0, otherLen, buf, count);
return new String(0, count + otherLen, buf);
}
```

Comment: isn't the concat being called on String?

Comment: So is toCharArray().  You cannot add two String without using any String methods because they are needed to at least access it. If you cannot use concat you can write a method which does the same thing.

Comment: yes, you can not write without using any of the String methods. But for this question, op is restricted to not use concat only not other methods.

Answer (score 0):

**java default support "+" for append string**

```
 String temp="some text";
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  temp=temp+i;
}
```

Or

```
   temp=temp+" some other text"
```